# GWT xml patterns

Tags: java, xml, gwt, xml-serialization, gwt-rpc

```
<servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-name>userServlet</servlet-name> 
    **<url-pattern>/helloservers/userService</url-pattern>**
</servlet-mapping>
```

Can some explain me what is the use of this `<url-pattern>` and why it is used?

"com.google.appengine.tools.development.LocalResourceFileServlet doGet
WARNING: No file found for: /helloservers/userService"

Am getting this error. Please explain why is comes? And what can be done to rectify it?

Answer (score 2):

Your URL is being served by [LocalResourceFileServlet](http://code.google.com/p/googleappengine/source/browse/trunk/java/src/main/com/google/appengine/tools/development/LocalResourceFileServlet.java?r=194%20LocalResourceFileServlet), ie. the server is trying to find a static file in your local file system - probably one called "userService".

I can think of two possible reasons for this:

- There's another servlet in your web.xml that has a `url-pattern` like `/helloservers/*`. This would overrule the servlet mapping you've quoted. If that's the case, you need to change one of the `url-pattern`s to avoid this ambiguity.
- The servlet container used in GWT may automatically use `LocalResourceFileServlet` when your servlet's `url-pattern` has no wildcards in it. In that case, change the `url-pattern` to  e.g. `/helloservers/userService/*` and request e.g. the url `/helloservers/userService/foo`